# Swagger don't detect controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller, swagger

`Swagger` don't detect any controllers and show error request of different type

[image]

SwaggerConfig:

```
@Configuration

public class SwaggerConfig {

    
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("tn.esprit.spring.controllers"))//Package+Classes
            .paths(PathSelectors.any()) //méthodes
            .build().apiInfo(apiInfo());
}
private ApiInfo apiInfo () {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("Swagger Configuration for Woman Area 5Project")
            .description("\"Spring Boot Swagger configuration\"")
            .version("1.0").build();
}

}
```

main:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class ProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

webSecurity config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/createcandidate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/downloadFile/{fileName:.+}").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/avatar/{id}").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/employees/{id}").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/dureeConge/{id}").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**");
}
```

Comment: are you able to hit controller-endpoints via postman or any other api-testing-tool ???

Comment: 404 not found ,it doesnt detect any link

Comment: okkay
can you share Controller Class Code
or check
is it `@Controller` or `@RestController` annotation ???

Comment: try adding @EnableWebMvc in SwaggerConfig extend with WebMvcConfigurer and override `@Override
 public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
  registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
 }`, this hopefully work